# Did Wile E. Coyote ever catch the Road Runner?

Tags: episode-identification, looney-tunes, wile-e-coyote-and-the-road-runner

In which animated cartoons did the Coyote even come close to catching the Road Runner? I know that he caught him once, but he didn’t know what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wile E Coyote finally catches his prey in a segment titled "[Soup or Sonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soup_or_Sonic)" which is part of a TV special produced in 1980. This is apparently the only time in "official" productions.

And the gag is, as you recall,  the Coyote has no idea what to do with the Road Runner and is asking the audience for advice/instruction.

[image: Wile E. Coyote holding two signs reading "Okay, wise guys, you always wanted me to catch him, now what do I do?"]

Comment: Not so much that he didn't know what to do - the coyote **always** wanted to eat the roadrunner.  It is just when he finally does catch the roadrunner he is shrunk down so small that it is impossible for him to eat the roadrunner.

Comment: I mean, look at it.  That tree-like thing to the right of the coyote is the raodrunner's leg.  What is the coyote supposed to do here?  Nibble on inedible roarunner claws?

Comment: @JRE I was trying to avoid explaining the whole joke

Comment: Whoa there, Wile, buddy, don't be putting this on us.  I don't remember ever wanting you to catch that thing.

Comment: Wow, who would have thought Wile E. Coyote was the first ever live streamer?

Answer (score 1):

According to this video there are an additonal two cartoons besides for the accepted answer where Wile E Coyote catches the Road Runner (I am not sure how to embed it): "Hopalong Casualty" (Chuck Jones, 1960) and "The Solid Tin Coyote" (Rudy Larriva, 1966).

https://fb.watch/aTDwaKq1Nd/

I believe it depends how one defines "catch". In these two cartoons, Wile E. Coyote does catch the road runner, but the road runner manages to escape. However, OP asked for cartoons where Wile E Coyote "came close to catching" and these two cartoons definitely fit the bill.